# Mathematical relation between aperture and DOF

Tags: aperture, depth-of-field, calculations

I know that aperture and DOF are inversely proportional. But, can anybody explain to me the Physics/Optics behind that? What's the mathematical relation that relates aperture with DOF?

Comment: It's primarily a *geometric* relation that explains it. Of course that geometric relationship can be expressed in mathematical terms, but it is first and foremost a geometrical relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has [all of the DoF formulae you probably ever need](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth_of_field#DOF_formulae). You may now begin to see why [optics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optics) is a field of physics unto itself.

You aren't going to be able to learn these equations and do them in your head to map an ƒ number to a depth of field in, say, feet. This is why there are so many DoF calculators floating around. [I wrote one](http://fcalc.net/) of [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=dof+calculator).